# Eigenvalues of skew hermitian matrices are purely imaginary

Tags: linear-algebra

$A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n }$ is skew hermitian if $A^*=-A $. Show that eigenvalue of skew hermitian matrices are purely imaginary.

#### Try:

Let $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$.
We know $$(Av)^* v =  v^* A^* v = v^* (-A) v = - v^* (Av)=-v^* \lambda A= - \lambda v^* v$$

On the other hand,

$$ (Av)^* v = (\lambda v)^* v = \overline{\lambda} v^* v $$

And so $- \lambda = \overline{\lambda}$ so $\lambda$ is purely imaginary. IS this correct appraoch ?

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes. You can also observe that $iA$ is Hermitean and hence has real eigenvalues.